# polynomial in entire function with polynomial coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function. Assume that there are polynomials $p_0, \ldots , p_n(z)$, not all zero, such that $p_n(z)(f(z))^n + p_{n−1}(z)(f(z))^{n−1} + \cdots + p_0(z) = 0$. Prove that f is a polynomial.

Comment: My initial thought was to use the characterization that an entire function is a polynomial iff it has a pole at infinity; but then I realized I need the polynomial to be a non-constant in that case. 
I was also trying to differentiate $\sum_i^{n} p_i(z)(f(z))^i$ to show that for some large $N$, $f^{(N)}(z)$ is a constant but I didn't get much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may assume $p_n(z)\ne 0.$ Suppose $f$ is not a polynomial. Then
$$
p_0(z)=-f(z)\left[p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-1} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + \cdots + p_1(z)\right]$$
yields 
$$
p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-1} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + \cdots + p_1(z)=0,$$
since $p_0(z)$ is a polynomial. Then
$$p_1(z)=-f(z)\left[p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-3} + \cdots + p_2(z)\right]$$
yields$$
p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-3} + \cdots + p_2(z)=0.$$
Eventually we have
$$p_n(z)f(z) + p_{n-1}(z)=0,$$
and $$p_{n-1}(z)=-p_n(z)f(z)$$ yields $p_n(z)=0$. It's a contradiction.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution which makes use of complex analysis, but sure this works :)

Comment: How did you get $p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-1} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + \cdots + p_1(z)=0$?

Comment: Since $f(z)$ is entire we can write it as $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$, but if LHS is polynomial and on the RHS we have product of two terms, a polynomial and an entire function (non-zero WLOG) then the polynomial on the RHS must be 0?
I don't see why this should be wrong?

Comment: @debanjana   You are correct. We suppose $f$ is not a polynomial, it's expansion $\sum a_nz^n$ has infinitely many non-zero terms. If $p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-1} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + \cdots + p_1(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ has a non-zero term, for instance, $c_0\ne 0$ or $c_nz^n, c_n\ne 0$ for some $n\ge 1$, then 
$f(z)[p_n(z)(f(z))^{n-1} + p_{n-1}(z)(f(z))^{n-2} + \cdots + p_1(z)]$ is not a polynomial. But LHS $p_0(z)$ is a polynomial. A contradiction. This argument is very elementary and simple. Of course we can take another approach. But simple is best.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume $p_n\not \equiv 0.$ The given equality implies

$$\tag 1 |p_n(z)||f(z)|^n = |\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p_{k}(z)f(z)^{k}| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_{k}(z)||f(z)|^{k}.$$

We'll show $(1)$ implies $|f(z)|$ has no more than polynomial growth at $\infty.$ As is well known, this implies $f$ is a polynomial.

Let $E= \{z\in \mathbb C\: |f(z)|\le 1\}.$ Obviously $|f(z)|$ has no more than polynomial growth as $z\to \infty$ within $E.$

Now consider $z\in \mathbb C \setminus E.$ Because $|f(z)|>1,$ we can say that by $(1),$

$$ |p_n(z)||f(z)|^n   \le |f(z)|^{n-1}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_{k}(z)|.$$

Dividing by $|f(z)|^{n-1}$ then gives

$$|p_n(z)||f(z)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_{k}(z)|.$$

Because $p_n \not \equiv 0,$ there is a constant $c>0$ such that $|p_n(z)|>c$ for large $|z|.$ For such $z\in \mathbb C \setminus E,$ we then have

$$c|f(z)| \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|p_{k}(z)|.$$

This implies $|f(z)|$ has has no more than polynomial growth as $z\to \infty$ within $\mathbb C \setminus E,$ and the proof is finished.